# Need to create a matrix from 2 array in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have two arrays:

```
array_1: 1 2 3 4 5 6 
array_2: 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6
```

The size of the two arrays are same. Now we need to print in such format,

```
1  with 0.1
1  with 0.2
1  with 0.3
1 with  0.4
1  with 0.5

2  with  0.1
2  with  0.2
2  with  0.3
2  with  0.4
2  with    0.5
2 with    0.6



6  with   0.1
6  with  0.2
6  with  0.3
6  with  0.4
6  with  0.5
6  with  0.6
```

Please help me how to print that in Perl?

Comment: is the number of blank lines an algorithmic constraint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my @array1 = qw(1 2 3 4 5 6 );
my @array2 = qw(0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6);
foreach my $item (@array1){
    foreach (@array2){
        print "$item with $_\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/736Zdx)

Comment: Superb Chankey Pathak. It resolves :)

Comment: Please refer http://learn.perl.org.